# Keyboard mapping program, different settings for different keyboards?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

At work I have an Apple keyboard that a friend bought me.  I used it for a long time on my desktop, but have recently switched to using my laptop for everything.  On my desktop, I had long ago remapped my keys (windows >< alt, print screen, etc).  Today on the laptop I installed an app I found called Sharp Keys and when I rebooted for it to take effect, I quickly discovered it affects the laptop keyboard as well.

So in short, does anyone know a way I can map the keys on a USB keyboard but **not** the attached keyboard?

Comment: don't know, but if you don't use 2 keyboards at one time then a workaround would be a program that would switch between different keyboard profiles/mappings quickly, though that,  I don't know either, but may be worth a search if you still don't find the actual thing you ask about

Comment: Yeah, if the USB keyboard is hooked up I have no need for the laptop keyboard.

Comment: a solution you can use is MSKLC, it definitely works. What happens is you get the MSKLC program, you define the output of each keyboard key, you save  the file. You give the language a name e.g. oojyboojy and layout wobbledeedoo.  (i.e. whatever you want to call it. you could call it language english, layout wobbledeedoo). But it may be best to give it a unique name for language. And anybody that types foreign languages in, knows there's a way to change languages too from the taskbar and you can assign a keyboard shortcut too. You could take that route and get manage it, write an answer

Comment: the MSKLC program is if I recall, able to make an EXE or MSI that you run and it automatically adds your "language" or language-layout" combo, to windows.  You would still then set windows so  you have the option in the taskbar to switch languages.

Comment: actually as MSKLC didn't work by swapping keys, like other utilities did(you can make a key like 'a' produce a string of a variety of characters) , it is very likely (if I recall the limitation correctly!) that MSKLC doesn't let you "map" or rather, do much unique of your own, with ctrl, alt, print screen. like swapping them.

Comment: @barlop I like that solution.  PLease post as an answer.

Comment: Did you use that solution recently? If so then maybe you could write an answer. I'm fine with that, i've got 4.7K rep anyway ;-) Plus you might have useful input about it if you've used it recently.

Comment: No, I've since bought a new laptop and have a completely different setup.  :(  But your idea seems totally plausible.